# Failed to init DatabaseManager: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql

i can't to solve this problemm all week, and looking for answer's and read some solutions but it's still not working...
I can to get connection to MySQL database from OracleSQLDEveloper and from IntellIj(when i connecting from DataBase plugin installed in IntellIj - i mean the button in the right side of intellij).
**BUT** when i am write my own code -> i am always get fail to connect...
My database working on virtual server - and i am use the standart database to learning.
I think my connection link is right becase other programs can to connect to DataBase.
my MySQLServices is running and antiVirus is off and WIndows protection is off.
i am working with the last possible driver and even try a maven link driver and last possible JDK 17.
I can't get connection from code with intellIj and in netBeans with the same code

'''public class DatabaseManager {

```
private static DatabaseManager instanse = new DatabaseManager();

private static final String DOMAIN_STRING = "192.168.56.103:1521";
private static final String DB_NAME = "XEPDB1";
private static final String USER_NAME = "hr";
private static final String PASSWORD = "hr";
private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://" + DOMAIN_STRING + "/" + DB_NAME + "?user="
        + USER_NAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD;
private Connection connection;

private DatabaseManager(){
    super();
    try {
        init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to init DatabaseManager: "+e);
    } 
}

public static DatabaseManager getInstanse() {
    return instanse;
}

private void init() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded successfully!");
    System.out.println("CONNECTION_STRING: "+CONNECTION_STRING);
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
    System.out.println("Connected to database "+DB_NAME);
}
```

---

CONNECTION_STRING: jdbc:mysql://192.168.56.103:1521/XEPDB1?user=hr&password=hr
Failed to init DatabaseManager: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
'''

Comment: Can you “telnet 192.168.56.103 1521” ?

Comment: this is adress of my virtual machine and other programs easly connect with this parameters

Comment: What do you mean by “easily connect”? HAve you checked the connectivity between sql client & database?

Comment: yes. i can to connect to DataBase from Oracle SQL DEveloper and from IntellIj but in intellIj this connection not from code - it's connection from fitcher of intellij.